# After upgrading Struts to 2.5.10.1 no such method error

Tags: struts2, log4j, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror

I upgraded the Struts jar to 2.5.10.1. But I get the following error. Initialy I had the Log4J 2.5 jar and I migrated it to Log4j 2.7.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerRegistry.<init>(LoggerRegistry.java:96)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerRegistry.<init>(LoggerRegistry.java:92)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLoggerContext.<init>(SimpleLoggerContext.java:67)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLoggerContextFactory.<clinit>(SimpleLoggerContextFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.<clinit>(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:531)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:116)
```

following are the libraries I used in my project.

> ```
> antlr-2.7.6.jar
> asm-3.3.jar
> asm-commons-3.3.jar
> asm-tree-3.3.jar
> cglib-3.2.6.jar
> commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
> commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
> commons-digester-1.8.jar
> commons-email-1.2.jar
> commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar
> commons-io-2.4.jar
> commons-lang3-3.4.jar
> commons-logging-4.0.6.jar
> commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
> dom4j-1.6.1.jar
> freemarker-2.3.23.jar
> hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
> hibernate3.jar
> javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
> json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
> jta-1.1.jar
> log4j-api-2.7.jar
> log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar
> mail.jar
> ognl-3.1.12.jar
> poi-3.9.jar
> slf4j-api-1.7.25 (1).jar
> slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
> sslext-1.2-0.jar
> struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
> struts2-convention-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
> struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar
> struts2-jquery-chart-plugin-3.7.0.jar
> struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.1.jar
> struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.1.jar
> struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin-3.7.1.jar
> struts2-json-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
> xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar
> ```

How to fix this?

Comment: There's likely a version conflict somewhere in your hierarchy, but without digging, I don't know which/where. What version of Java are you running?

Comment: I'm using 1.7. is it a log4j lib version error or problem with another jar???

Comment: You have a jar mess.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove asm jars from the class path.

The version of Struts 2.5.10.1 doesn't have dependency on xwork-core 2.3.15.